# Mysql connection issue in docker file

Tags: node.js, docker

I want to create a docker image of node js application. It gives error   while running, I think I have to add SQL code to docker file but do not know how. I do not want to do with docker composer, just want everything in one docker file.

```
RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app


ADD package*.json /app/

RUN cd /app && npm install

COPY  . .

RUN cd /app && npm run build

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV PORT=3000

ENV MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL=mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/db

EXPOSE ${PORT}
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

---

```
> ah-feedback-service@1.0.0 migrate /app
> node ./dist/migrate

Migrating schemas (alter existing schema)
Connection fails: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
It will be retried for the next request.
events.js:182
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1174:14)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue         (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
at Protocol.handshake     (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
at PoolConnection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
at Pool.getConnection (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
at MySQL.connect (/app/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/lib/mysql.js:90:17)
at Object.initializeDataSource [as initialize] (/app/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/lib/mysql.js:44:28)
at Mysql8DataSource.DataSource.setup (/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:493:19)
at Mysql8DataSource.DataSource (/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:138:8)
at Mysql8DataSource (/app/dist/datasources/mysql-8.datasource.js:25:9)
at value_promise_1.transformValueOrPromise.args (/app/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/resolver.js:46:16)
at Object.transformValueOrPromise (/app/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/value-promise.js:227:16)
at Object.instantiateClass (/app/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/resolver.js:41:34)
at Binding._setValueGetter [as _getValue] (/app/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/binding.js:393:59)
at resolution_session_1.ResolutionSession.runWithBinding.s (/app/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/binding.js:199:29)
at value_promise_1.tryWithFinally (/app/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/resolution-session.js:69:53)
at Object.tryWithFinally (/app/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/value-

promise.js:158:18)
npm info lifecycle ah-feedback-service@1.0.0~migrate: Failed to exec migrate script
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ah-feedback-service@1.0.0 migrate: `node ./dist/migrate`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
```

Comment: At that point in the runtime, is the mysql service up at that endpoint?

Comment: You really should run your database in a separate container, at which point it won't be on 127.0.0.1.  The setup of multi-process containers is significantly more complex, and the lifetime of your application (delete and recreate on any code change) and the database (never ever delete) are very different.